# When do I ask for an advance/upfront payment

Tags: payment-terms, working-from-home, project-management

I have the project agreement ready which I will send to all my clients before website development begins.

But I am confused about when to ask for an upfront payment?

Generally, when I send agreements before asking any upfront, a few clients deny working further in the project. So what I decided is, I will charge them upfront and clearly mention it in the invoice itself (which I issue before any agreement). After taking the upfront payment, I will send the agreement to the client where it will be clearly defined that the advanced payment has already been made. And other milestones will be paid as per the agreement... which is defined clearly in the agreement.

Is this a proper way to handle this? Do you have any advice or recommendations?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoice *before* any formal contact is agreed upon? I'd walk away if that was proposed to me.

Asking for payment before disclosing any agreement terms is somewhat underhanded and shady. And if you are not refunding that initial payment should the client  *not* wish to agree to your contract, you're really taking advantage of people.

**Typically, the initial deposit is paid at the time of *singing* a contract, not before.**

Comment: Actually, I want to refund the amount if the contract is declined. Why would I take payment for nothing... Yeah its definitely taking advantage. I dont intend to do that.

Comment: But working that way also ensures me that the client is authentic and trusty. Because here generally I get low paying clients, and few of them just doesn't like entering into any legal agreements. They neither understand this is needed in Web development and nor do they want to. So these few clients reject after all my efforts in even drafting an agreement.

Comment: If anyone won't sign your contract, walk away **always**.